# Apachesolr query - filter by text in fields

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7

I'm constructing an apachesolr query in my Drupal module programmatically and have had success with some aspects, but am still struggling with others.

So far, I have been able to construct a query that can search for specific text and limit the results based on terms to be filtered by with the following code:

```
$subquery_region->addFilter('tid', $term->tid);
$query->addFilterSubQuery($subquery_region, 'OR', 'AND');
```

What I'd like to achieve next is to be able to narrow the search further by adding a filter for finding certain text within a specific **field** in the node.  Has anyone been able to do this.

I've been researching online and have tried lots of different ways such as adding the filter directly to the main search query

```
$query->addParam('fl', 'ss_my_field');
$query->addFilter("ss_my_field", "field_substring_to_search_for");
```

As well as breaking that out into a subquery to add to the main search query

```
$subquery_test = apachesolr_drupal_query("Test");
$subquery_test->addParam('fl', 'ss_my_field');
$subquery_test->addFilter("ss_my_field", "field_substring_to_search_for");
$query->addFilterSubQuery($subquery_test, 'OR', 'AND');
```

But none of these are working.  They are returning an empty set, even though I know the substring exists in the field I'm adding as a filter and it has been indexed.  I have verified through the apachesorl views module that the search index has been populated with that field and can see the substring exists.

Is there anything wrong with my syntax or the way I'm building the query?

If you know how to add filters for searching for text within certain fields, please share!  It may not even be done with the addFilter function, but that's all I have been trying so far.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to create an index for that specific field.

```
function hook_apachesolr_update_index(&$document, $node) {
  $document->ss_your_field_name = $node->your_field_name;
}
```

where ss_* is the pattern.
ss_* -> String
is_* -> Integer
im_* -> Integer, Multivalued

After that you have to 
1. delete the index - admin/settings/apachesolr/index
2. re-index the content
3. run the cron
4. check the filter that you created - admin/reports/apachesolr/index

Then, you can add filters

```
$query->addFilter("ss_your_field_name", "value");
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Ram, thank you so much for your help so far.  The first part worked beautifully and I can see now that my fields are added to the index.  However, adding them with the addFilter() function as described isn't returning anything.  Any other ideas on format.  I'm editing my question to include everything I've tried so far that hasn't worked...

Answer (score 0):

```
function hook_apachesolr_modify_query(&$query, &$params, $caller){
  $subquery = apachesolr_drupal_query();
  $subquery->add_filter("ss_my_field", "field_substring_to_search_for");
  $query->add_subquery($subquery, "AND");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ram.  That's exactly what I've been doing, except my code in my question is the Drupal 7 version of those functions.  It's still not 100% working for me, but I +1ned your first answer because it's definitely getting me closer.  Thanks again!